# CFA: examining model fit and modification indices for single factor variables before examining the full model.

Tags: confirmatory-factor

I'm examining a questionnaire believed to have two-factors (7 items on each variable) from previous Exploratory Factor Analysis. Looking at it using Confirmatory Factor Analysis (CFA), the fit is rather poor (RMSEA around .10; CFI around .90). So now I'm going to examine the modification indices, but I wonder whether I should:

1. Examine the modification indices in the two-factor model, 
   OR
2. Examine the CFA models of each of the two variables independently first and their modification indices (and potentially remove/adjust items to fit the two independent CFA models first); and then when the two variables have a good fit examine the two-factor solution and potentially remove/adjust items.

Lastly, does anyone have any good reference for any of these approaches.

Any help is much appreciated, 
Gorp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is best to go with alternative 2. as this examines the unidimensionality of each scale. See Ziegler and Hagemann (2015; Testing the Unidimensionality of Items: Pitfalls and Loopholes; *European Journal of Psychological Assessment*) stating:

"start... with testing the measurement models for each new scale 
score..., followed by testing structural models including measurement models for overlapping traits..., should provide much better evidence with regard to unidimensionality."